# Track skipping method

Tags: java, audio-player

The track is playing with no problem. Whenever I click on next button it stops first song and then plays next random song. But the flaw is it is not pausing the second song. And also after second song whenever I click on NEXT button it does not stop the song that is playing and plays another song simultaneously.

I tried flushing the clip and also closing it. This code is current version.

public class Version_6 {

```
static File[] songs = new File[5];
public static int currentSongIndex;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    songs[0] = new File("LoverBoi.WAV");
    songs[1] = new File("Wing.WAV");
    songs[2] = new File("rip.WAV");
    songs[3] = new File("rainOnMe.WAV");
    songs[4] = new File("wm.WAV");

    // playSong(songs[getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(0, 4)]);
    try {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        jf.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg")))));

        jf.pack();
        JButton button_start = new JButton("Start");
        JButton button_pause = new JButton("Pause");
        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        Container pane = jf.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane.add(button_start);
        pane.add(button_pause);
        pane.add(btnNext);
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        pane.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        button_start.setBounds(750, 450, 100, 100);
        button_start.setBounds(550, 250, 100, 100);
        btnNext.setBounds(350, 50, 100, 100);
        button_start.setVisible(false);
        btnNext.setVisible(true);

        AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs[getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(0, 4)]);
        Clip clip;
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInput);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                {
                    clip.stop();
                    clip.flush();
                    clip.drain();
                    clip.close();
                    if (clip.isRunning() == true) {

                    }

                    nextSong(clip, getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(0, 4));
                }
            }
        });
        button_start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pauseAndContinue(clip);
                button_start.setVisible(false);
                button_pause.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button_pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
                pauseAndContinue(clip);
                button_start.setVisible(true);
                button_pause.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

/**
 * @param clip
 *            currently loaded clip This method is for playing and pausing
 *            the clip
 */
public static void pauseAndContinue(Clip clip) {
    if (clip.isRunning() == true) {
        clip.stop();

    } else if (clip.isRunning() == false) {
        clip.start();
        // clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
}

/**
 * @param chosenClip
 *            clip that is playing right now (or should i say "loaded right
 *            now")
 * @param currentSongIndex
 *            Array index of current opened file
 */
public static void nextSong(Clip chosenClip, int currentSongIndex) {
    if (chosenClip.isRunning() == true) {
        chosenClip.stop();
        chosenClip.flush();
        chosenClip.close();
    }
    if (currentSongIndex + 1 > 4)
        currentSongIndex = 0;
    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
    playSong(songs[currentSongIndex]);

}

/**
 * @param songFile
 *            chosen song file This method is for playing the song
 */
public static void playSong(File songFile) {
    AudioInputStream audioInput;
    try {
        audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songFile);
        Clip clip;
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInput);
        clip.start();
        // clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

I expect whenever I click on NEXT button it plays next song and when it comes to last song after playing it, it starts from the beggining again.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are creating local variables for clip and then trying to stop the wrong clip.

First, create a static Clip variable at the top of your class:

```
static File[] songs = new File[5];
public static int currentSongIndex;
static Clip clip;
```

Next, make sure that you reference the static `Clip` variable in your `playSong` method by using `this.clip` instead of `Clip clip`:

```
public static void playSong(File songFile) {
    AudioInputStream audioInput;
    try {
        audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songFile);
        //Deleted this line:
        //Clip clip;
        //This line has been updated:
        this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInput);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And in your main method:

```
    AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs[getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(0, 4)]);
    //Deleted this line:
    //Clip clip;
    //Changed this line:
    this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInput);
    clip.start();
    clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Now it should function as intended.

Comment: First thanks for sparing time. Unfortunately it won't work. Just same as before.

Comment: When I click NEXT button it skips the first song. But not skipping second one.

Comment: @Meld If it works for the first one, then why does it not work for the second? The best thing to do is to step through your code and look at the differences. You probably need to make your `AudioInputStream audioInput` a static variable at the top of the class, and use `this.audioInput` instead of a local variable. However, you should not start the first song in the main method, it should all be done in one place (the `playSong` method), this would also solve your problem.